# insert radio button inside payment_fields WooCommerce instead of credit card form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I an developing a custom payment method for WooCommerce. I want to add three radio button after my payment method is selected.

[image]

I have added this via browsers's inspect element toll. How can i do this and get the value of radio button inside the extend WooCommerce payment gateway class.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you done any research around this? Please show what you have done and where you are facing problem.

Comment: @zipkundan i used this public function payment_fields(){
my_form which consist of radio buttons
}
in my custom payment method plugin you can see in the screen shot i got the form under my payment method but problem is i want this radio button in order detail page as well .i want to get the value of selected button inside my class

Comment: @zipkundan i have an idea but not getting any help on it either. idea is , at the time of installation  assign new custom field to woocommerce order type post.then give the name of the custom field to my form fields and then at the time of order placement i'll be able to get the values of custom field as well but how can i assign custom field to order type post at the time of my plugin installation.???

Comment: You should need at minima to provide the code of your custom payment gateway in the question itself. without it your question is too vague and unclear.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec look at this question i posted again ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365088/insert-radio-button-inside-payment-fields-function-woocommerce-instead-of-credit